# mousedown event not happening

Tags: javascript, jquery

in the snippet below, only the 'mousemove' event is working. 'mousedown' has no effect and I'm not able to decipher why this is happening. If I replace 'mousedown' with 'click', it does work, however I want to use mousedown so the fadeOut event happens immediately (at the start of a click, rather than using click which relies on the users mouse going down and then back up.

```
$('.issue-carousel').on({
    // On mousemove, controls follow cursor
    mousemove: function(e) {
        var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
        $('.drag-indicator').css({
            left: relX,
            top: relY
        });
    },
    mousedown: function() {
       $('.drag-indicator').fadeOut(300);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you see any errors in browser's console?

Comment: [Works for me.](https://jsfiddle.net/zdm5c3mh/) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: your code is in working state .... I think you have implementation issue

Comment: Also works fine for me. The only bit that doesn't is the mouse down bit, but I think that's technically because you're clicking on the `.drag-indicator`-rather than the `.issue carousel`. See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/o3cdLjp7/1/ where I have changed the click target.

Comment: Hi, no console errors!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment, your code works fine - with one exception. The `mousedown` `fadeout` doesn't work because you technically aren't clicking the carousel but instead the `drag indicator`. I've updated the code as per below where I have changed the mousedown target accordingly;

```
$('.issue-carousel').on({
    // On mousemove, controls follow cursor
    mousemove: function(e) {
        var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
        var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
        var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
        $('.drag-indicator').css({
            left: relX,
            top: relY
        });
    }
});

$('.drag-indicator').on({
    mousedown: function(e){
    $(this).fadeOut(300);
  }
})
```

A working fiddle can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/o3cdLjp7/2/

Comment: @dungey_140: No, that's not how it works. The full content of your question must be **in** your question, not just linked. Links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future, and people shouldn't have to go off-site to help you. Put a [mcve] **in** the question, ideally using Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button) to make it runnable ([here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @dungey_140 - Unfortunately as T.J says above, if you can reproduce your problem here in a stack snippet (or in a jsfiddle/codepen at least) we can help you further. The link to your tunnel will expire when you close it (additionally, it's far too slow to load).

Comment: OK thanks Lewis. I will mark your answer as correct although I think I will have to continue using 'click', as I'm not able to get the same error when transferring the issue to Stack. Very odd!